# Apply Hamiltonian to position eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

Let $\hat{H}$ be the free Hamilton operator, is it then true that

$$\langle {\bf r}| \hat{H} ~=~ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \Delta \langle {\bf r}|~?$$

Where $\Delta\equiv \nabla^2$. I currently don't see why this should hold.

Comment: In the sense of distributions this is perfectly legitimate; the derivatives of the delta function are easily defined. Keep in mind, however that what you do obtain is a distribution, as it is the position eigenstate, that does not belong to the Hilbert space (i.e. is not a wavefunction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\langle \mathbf r |\hat H = \langle \mathbf r|\hat T = \frac{1}{2m}\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2$$

Taking the inner product with a general state yields

$$\langle \mathbf r |\hat H|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2m}\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2|\psi\rangle$$

Since the position eigenstates are complete

$$\int d \mathbf r\,| \mathbf r \rangle \langle \mathbf r | = 1$$

we have

$$\frac{1}{2m}\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2m}\int d \mathbf r'\,\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2| \mathbf r' \rangle \, \langle \mathbf r' |\psi \rangle$$

But

$$\langle \mathbf r' |\psi \rangle = \psi( \mathbf r')$$

and

$$\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2| \mathbf r' \rangle = -\hbar^2\;\nabla^2\delta(\mathbf r - \mathbf r')$$

thus

$$\frac{1}{2m}\langle \mathbf r|\hat P^2|\psi\rangle = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\int d \mathbf r'\,\nabla^2\delta(\mathbf r - \mathbf r') \, \psi( \mathbf r') = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \psi(\mathbf r) = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \langle \mathbf r |\psi \rangle$$

so

$$\langle \mathbf r |\hat P^2 = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \langle \mathbf r|$$